# Insert ASP code (with parameter) in Javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have some ASP code that creates some Javascript code :

```
response.write "<A href='HSVideo.asp?FileName=" & FileName & "' onclick="+V+"return hs.htmlExpand(this,{"
response.write " objectType:'iframe', preserveContent:false, width:670, height:570" 
response.write "})"+V+" onmouseup=" & V & "AddOne('" & FileName & "')" & V & ">&nbsp;ADD ONE&nbsp;</A>"
```

The AddOne function is as follows

```
<script language="javascript"> <!-- runat="server"> -->
  function AddOne(NF) {
     alert(NF);
  } 
</script>
```

However, in the AddOne function, I would like the following ASP code to work instead of a trivial alert (NF)

```
Set Cnn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strConn="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+Session("globalDB")+"db.MDB"
cnn.open StrConn
rs.Open "SELECT FileNameMP4, Num FROM TableNum WHERE FileNameMP4='" + NF + "'", cnn, 3, 3
Num=rs("Num")
rs("Num")=Num+1
rs.Update
rs.Close
cnn.Close
```

This ASP code, if inserted in a single ASP page, performs its role very well (which is only to increase the Num field by 1).
Basically, how to change the AddOne function ?
How to act?
Thanks for your attention

Comment: you need to create a service endpoint for your SQL operation - your client function AddOne will call this.  but change this: ```"SELECT FileNameMP4, Num FROM TableNum WHERE FileNameMP4='" + NF + "'"```  to use parameterised query, or entity framework - as this is VERY vulnerable to injection attack ref: ```https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado?view=sql-server-ver15```

Comment: or ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59040198/ado-parameterized-queries-with-subqueries-error```

Comment: I do not know this "service endpoint" and, despite having tried to document myself, I did not understand how to apply this technique to my case.
I am quite familiar with Classic ASP and have little knowledge about Javascript.
This involves incrementing a counter of a certain record of a MsAccess database (not SQLServer) by 1.
This on the occasion of the "onmouseup" event as reported in the very first ASP code I wrote in the first part of this post.